# BITS service will not start on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, bits

The BITS service will not start on my machine (Windows 8, 64-bit), (preventing Windows Updates from being downloaded):

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc start bits
SERVICE_NAME: bits
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 264
        FLAGS              :
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc query bits
SERVICE_NAME: bits
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1066  (0x42a)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 2147943458  (0x80070422)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0`

## System Logs

I get the following messages in various logs when attempting to start the service:

In the System Log:

`The Background Intelligent Transfer Service service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.`

`The BITS service failed to start.  Error 0x80070422.`

In the Bits-Client Analytical Log:

`The service is creating its performance counters.
The service is generating its common global data.`

In the Bits-Client Operational Log:

`The BITS service shut down successfully, but it was delayed for 142997.062 seconds. This might cause delays when you turn off your computer. For more information on the delay, enable the analytic log for BITS, then stop and restart the BITS service.`

(confusing, since the service seems to terminate after a second or so)

What I've tried so far to no avail (some of these due to originally thinking the issues was with Windows Update itself):

## Dependent Services

Looking in Services.msc

The BITS service is listed as startup type: Automatic

The dependent services are listed as:

- COM+ Event System
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC)

Both of which are running.

## Renaming Directories

- Renaming C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Network\Downloader
- Renaming windir\Catroot2 directory.
- Renaming windir\SoftwareDistribution directory.

## SFC

Running sfc /scannow reports:

`Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios.`

Looking at the log file, the relevent files seem to be unrelated to this issue:

    `Line 6513: 2015-08-05 10:28:55, Info                  CSI    0000058d Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_prncacla.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17415_none_95dd5540d57f8c01\Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB do not match actual file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" :
    Line 6516: 2015-08-05 10:29:25, Info                  CSI    0000058f Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_prncacla.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17415_none_95dd5540d57f8c01\Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB do not match actual file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" :
    Line 8008: 2015-08-05 10:51:49, Info                  CSI    000008db Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_prncacla.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17415_none_95dd5540d57f8c01\Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB do not match actual file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" :
    Line 8011: 2015-08-05 10:51:50, Info                  CSI    000008dd Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_prncacla.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17415_none_95dd5540d57f8c01\Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB do not match actual file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" :`

Full log here:

https://gist.github.com/benblamey/65e2831822525de87758

## VirusScan

I've run a virus scan with ClamAV, reports no issues.

## BitsAdmin

Attempting to list the jobs in the queue times out, complaining that the service isn't running.

## Process Monitor

Attempting to start the service while the SysInternals process monitor  is running, gives me the following output (filtering to where the process name is svchost):

https://gist.github.com/benblamey/be97b978cdf5bd685a9d

Done the usual Googling, but many of the articles and tools suggested don't seem suitable for Windows 8. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The fix was simple: The Network Location Awareness Service wasn't running.

(Annoying that this isn't listed as a dependent service!)